# DELL Latitude 7400 Intel Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]

Tags: dell

Lately on-boarded a new laptop DELL Latitude 7400 where I'm facing frequent service (internet) disruption where it's connected over the Wifi network WPA2, Enterprise connection.

At the time of service failure, logs captured are as below:

```
Dec 17 11:55:01 MaPC CRON[76403]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)                        
Dec 17 11:59:30 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: WPA: Group rekeying completed with e0:0e:da:8e:22:a2 [GTK=CCMP]          
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC NetworkManager[1078]: <info>  [1608195675.8267] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE  
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC whoopsie[1936]: [12:01:15] offline                                                                   
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC dbus-daemon[1076]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=1078 co
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...                                    
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC dbus-daemon[1076]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'           
Dec 17 12:01:15 MaPC systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.                                       
Dec 17 12:01:16 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. 
Dec 17 12:01:16 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 17 12:01:16 MaPC goa-daemon[2043]: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 2 — Error resolving “autodiscover.internetmail.test.net”: Name or service not known    
Dec 17 12:01:17 MaPC NetworkManager[1078]: <info>  [1608195677.3276] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 17 12:01:17 MaPC whoopsie[1936]: [12:01:17] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3                 
Dec 17 12:01:17 MaPC whoopsie[1936]: [12:01:17] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3  
Dec 17 12:01:17 MaPC whoopsie[1936]: [12:01:17] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3                   
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. 
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC gnome-shell[2230]: Can not connect to https://weathermap.org/city/108410?APPID=b941621f899bb8#012Host unreachable         
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC whoopsie[1936]: [12:01:18] online                                                                    
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. 
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 17 12:01:18 MaPC goa-daemon[2043]: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 2 — Error resolving “autodiscover.internetmail.test.net”: Name or service not known    
Dec 17 12:01:19 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. 
Dec 17 12:01:20 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 17 12:01:20 MaPC goa-daemon[2043]: goa_ews_client_autodiscover() failed: 2 — Error resolving “autodiscover.internetmail.test.net”: Name or service not known    
Dec 17 12:01:20 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. 
Dec 17 12:01:27 MaPC systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.                                            
Dec 17 12:05:01 MaPC CRON[87061]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)                        
Dec 17 12:14:53 MaPC /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2076]: (EE) event9  - Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 33ms, your system is too slow    
Dec 17 12:15:01 MaPC CRON[97792]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)                        
Dec 17 12:17:01 MaPC CRON[99925]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)                             
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started                        
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25                        
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected             
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed                       
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully         
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 54:b2:61:a5:1d:aa 0                                  
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 2c:5a:0f:53:7b:ca 0                                  
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 60:0e:da:8d:13:a2 0                                  
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 60:0e:db:8f:22:a2 0                                    
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC wpa_supplicant[1114]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with f0:0e:ba:8f:22:a2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 17 12:19:38 MaPC kernel: [ 3621.001152] Rekeying PTK for STA e0:0e:da:8e:22:a2 but driver can't safely do that.       
Dec 17 12:20:10 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 10.60.20.104.                 
Dec 17 12:20:20 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.60.20.104.   
Dec 17 12:20:40 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.60.20.104.   
Dec 17 12:20:45 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.60.20.104.   
Dec 17 12:21:10 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 10.60.20.104.   
Dec 17 12:21:16 MaPC systemd-resolved[1001]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 10.60.20.104.
```

Till NetworkManager service restart internet service remains down.

Any relevant issue reported or already in the knowledgebase or any clue about it?

Thanks

Comment: Some HW details may be referred here; https://pastebin.com/JjBc19qd

Comment: Any Ubuntu/DELL expert here?